# Angular 10 - TextArea filled using string interpolation not displaying correctly if user edits

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a feature on my site that allows users to auto-format selected data to be used externally.

The formatted data still requires some level of editing from the user to be usable, which is where the problem arises.

The data is displayed in an editable text area so the the user doesn't have to copy/paste it elsewhere to make the required changes, but once any user edits have been made, the text area seems to lock in that data and not displaying new formatted data.

I've checked using console.log that the variable in question is being correctly set, it's just not being displayed.

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="15">{{ formattedData }}</textarea>
```

TypeScript:

```
formattedData;

formatData(dataToFormat) {
  this.formattedData = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dataToFormat.length; i++) {
    let temp = // do formatting here
    this.formattedData += temp + '\n';
}
```

Does any one have any idea why this is happening and what I can do to fix it? It would be preferable if I could keep the text area user editable if possible.

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pya4n?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: When/How is `formatData` called ?

Comment: It's called on a button that also displays the above text area. So that code runs every time the text area is displayed. The passed ```dataToFormat``` is tied to select records in a primeNG table

Comment: Have you tried adding a setTimeout `setTimeout(() => this.formattedData += temp + '\n';);` ?

Comment: @Random just tried this now but unfortunately it didn't make any difference

Comment: Created a stackblitz demo for you. It's working fine if the `formatData` has some data initailly. Check the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pya4n?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @iamentafaz thanks for creating that stackblitz demo, I was able to recreate the bug in it as well. The bug appears only when user edits the contents on the `textarea`. If you delete a letter from the text and click the format button again, the text doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Random, a cleaner solution would be to use `ngModel` on the `textarea` as follows:

```
<textarea rows="15" [(ngModel)]="formattedData"></textarea>
```

The TypeScript in the question doesn't need to be changed for this solution to work.

**Original Answer**

I am not sure what was causing the bug to happen, but I have found a solution by putting the `textarea` inside a `form` tag and using Angular's NgForm.

New HTML:

```
<form #formatForm="ngForm">
  <textarea rows="15" id="formatResults" name="formatResults" ngModel></textarea>
</form>
```

New TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('formatForm') formatForm: NgForm;

formatData(dataToFormat) {
  let formattedData = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dataToFormat.length; i++) {
    let temp = // do formatting here
    formattedData += temp + '\n';
  }

  this.formatForm.controls['formatResults'].setValue(formattedData);
}
```

Comment: omg of course yes. How could we miss that. You cannot use mustaches inside an input/textarea, you have to use ngModel, or formControl ! A nicer way would be `[(ngModel)]="formattedData"`, with the same TS code than in your question (no need ngForm)

Comment: That's a really good idea actually! I'll update my answer to include that as it's much simpler than using ngForm